# node js server is listening but not work

Tags: node.js

I have a node js server installed on a Linux virtual machine and started for the first time.
When I start the server it results in LISTEN and ESTABLISHED in the netstat table but when I try to load the content inside the browser I get "connection refused".
I start a server with **EXPRESS** library
I've tried:

- to set "**localhost**" as ip and "**3000**" as port (**NOT WORK**)
- to set **process.env.IP** as ip and **process.env.PORT** as port (**NOT WORK**)
- to work with **iptables** (**NOT WORK**)

Can you help me?
Thanks

Code:

```
// initializing express-session middleware
var Session = require('express-session'),
    SessionStore = require('session-file-store')(Session);
var session = Session({ secret: 'pass', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true });

// creating new express app
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(session); // session support
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  req.session.uid = 1;
  res.send('Hi user #' + req.session.uid);
});

app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hi user #' + req.session.uid);
});
// attaching express app to HTTP server
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || '3000');

// creating new socket.io app
var ios = require('socket.io-express-session');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.use(ios(session)); // session support

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  console.log(socket.handshake.session);
});
```

Comment: Could you add your *server* `.js` file?

Comment: @kamauz - it will be helpful if you can provide the code snippet that made you conclude that your node server is listening and established.  The more information you provide the faster you'll get a helping hand.

Comment: @kamauz You are also running your browser from inside the same VM, correct? Not on the machine that's hosting the VM?

Comment: @Norguard yes, exactly